# typeahead.js onselect item redirect to new window

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js

I am use remote url with json response ( New typeahead.js)

**my javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('input.country').typeahead({
valueKey: 'name',
remote : {
url : 'example.in/d.php?query=%QUERY',
filter: function (parsedResponse) {
  var dataset = [];   
for (i = 0; i < parsedResponse.length; i++) {
              dataset.push({
                name: parsedResponse[i].name
              });
            }
if (parsedResponse.length == 0) {
              dataset.push({
                name: "No results" 
              }); }
            return dataset;
        },
},
});;
})
```

my json response :

[{"name":"Nokia 110",url:"example.com/nokia-110"},{"name":"Nokia 210",url:"example.com/nokia-210"}]

so how to give URL link on selected name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the template that Typeahead.js uses and in it you would display the URL.

See: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#datum

For a good templating system that works well with Typeahead.js I would recommend you look at http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/

Answer (score 5):

### Event Listener

```
$('input.country').on( 'typeahead:selected', function(event, selected_object, dataset) {
   window.location.href = selected_object.url
});
```

This assumes that your `selected_object` has an attribute called `url` that contains a valid URL to redirect your browser to. There are variations as to the best way to set and get this `url` attribute and value but you can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Toby for giving overall idea

Here Full coding.....I hope its easy for everyone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.q').typeahead({
      valueKey: 'name',
      remote : {
        url : 'http://example.com/chk.php?query=%QUERY',

        filter: function (parsedResponse) {
          var dataset = [];   

          for (i = 0; i < parsedResponse.length; i++) {
            dataset.push({
              name: parsedResponse[i].name,
              link:  parsedResponse[i].link
            });
          }

          if (parsedResponse.length == 0) {
            dataset.push({
              name: "No results" 
            }); 
          }

          return dataset;
        },
      },
    })
    .bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
      window.location.href = datum.link;
    });
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
        var path = "{{ route('home.autocompleteSearch') }}";
        var typeahead = $('input.typeahead');
        typeahead.typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.get(path, {query: query}, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
            },
            afterSelect: function (data) {
                window.location.replace(data.url);
            }
        });
```